# Making A imported(DllImport) C++ DLL thread safe for C#

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading

I was wondering what the "requirements" for a C++ dll being imported into C# using DllImport, to make it completely thread safe given the functions in the C++ Dll are very basic.

Comment: It's just like if you called the C++ function directly from C#, the same thread safety rules apply as if you'd have called your functions from C++.

Comment: It will never be more or less thread-safe than the C++ code.  So there are no requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There's no default protection, if that's what you're asking - it's as if you called the function from any other language.

If you need thread-safety, you'll need to make your own wrapper class that provides that safety, and make sure your code doesn't bypass that (just make the `DllImport`ed methods `private` within the wrapper class).